# Expected value of Y = (1/X) where $X \sim Gamma$

Tags: self-study, expected-value, gamma-distribution

I'm having some confusion over this statement here. Let $T_i \sim Exp(\lambda + \theta)$ and if they are all iid then $\sum_n T_i \sim Gamma(\alpha = n, \beta = 1/(\lambda + \theta))$

I want to find $E(\frac{1}{\sum_n T_i})$. I know I can't just do the reciprocal of $E(\sum_n T_i)$

Do I integrate over $\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{f(t)} dt$?

If I do this I get $\Gamma(\alpha) \beta^\alpha \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{t/\beta}}{t^\alpha} dt$ and I don't know if this is the right way to proceed since I end up with incomplete gamma?

I know that I'm supposed to end up with $\frac{\lambda + \theta}{n-1}$ as the answer but I'm not sure how the gamma is supposed to cancel out.

Comment: the density goes in the numerator......

Comment: and I think you mean the answer should be $(\lambda + \theta)/(n-1)$

Comment: The density should go in the numerator but would it still be the density function I'm integrating over if I want 1/X and not X? And yes you are correct about the answer, I'll fix that typo. Thanks

Comment: If $X$ is a random variable with density $f$, then for any (nice) function $G$, $\mathbb E[ G(X) ] = \int G(x)f(x)dx$

Comment: ... Or, as that's sometimes known, [the law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)

Comment: One easy way to do it is to apply the abovementioned law, and play 'spot the density', pull out the appropriate constants and cross out the integral of the density (since that integrates to 1).

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry, I saw your LOTUS comment but did not see your "spot the density" comment before I began writing my answer.

Comment: @Dilip You have nothing to be sorry for!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The calculation of $E\left[X^{-1}\right]$ when $X$ is a Gamma random variable with order parameter $n$ and rate parameter $\lambda$
requires recognition of the density of *another* Gamma random variable (with order
parameter $n-1$ and rate parameter $\lambda$) in the
integral given by the law of the unconscious statistician for 
$E\left[X^{-1}\right]$.  We have

$$\begin{align}
E\left[X^{-1}\right]&= 
\int_0^\infty \frac 1x \cdot \underbrace{\lambda \frac{(\lambda x)^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)}e^{-\lambda x}}_{\Gamma(n,\lambda)~\text{density}}\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \lambda\frac{\Gamma(n-1)}{\Gamma(n)}\int_0^\infty \underbrace{\lambda \frac{(\lambda x)^{n-2}}{\Gamma(n-1)}e^{-\lambda x}}_{\Gamma(n-1,\lambda)~\text{density}}\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \frac{\lambda}{n-1}
\end{align}$$
since for positive integer $k$, $\Gamma(k) = (k-1)!$.

Comment: Yea, the gamma's through me off quite a bit since I wasn't quite sure how to go about doing the integral. This explains how the gammas cancelled out so we get just n-1. Thanks!