Student T as an infinite gaussian mixture
I'm reasking this question to understand the answer. The question asks to show a gamma-weighted Gaussian distribution is equivalent to a Student t-distribution.
The accepted answer loses me when it says "the integral is immediate," essentially skipping the step where the insight lies.
The answer states:

The PDF of a Normal distribution is
$$f_{\mu, \sigma}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu
> )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}dx$$
but in terms of $\tau = 1/\sigma^2$ it is
$$g_{\mu, \tau}(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\tau}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{\tau(x-\mu )^2}{2 }}dx.$$
The PDF of a Gamma distribution is
$$h_{\alpha, \beta}(\tau) =\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}e^{-\frac{\tau}{\beta }} \tau^{-1+\alpha }\beta ^{-\alpha }d\tau.$$
Their product, slightly simplified with easy algebra, is therefore
$$f_{\mu, \alpha, \beta}(x,\tau)=\frac{1}{\beta^\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\tau\left(\frac{(x-\mu )^2}{2 } + \frac{1}{\beta}\right)}\tau^{-1/2+\alpha}d\tau dx.$$

Here's where I get lost.

Its inner part evidently has the form $\exp(-\text{constant}_1 \times\tau) \times \tau^{\text{constant}_2}d\tau$, making it a multiple of a
Gamma
function
when integrated over the full range $\tau=0$ to $\tau=\infty$.  That
integral therefore is immediate (obtained by knowing the integral of a
Gamma distribution is unity), giving the marginal distribution
$$f_{\mu, \alpha, \beta}(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\beta } \Gamma \left(\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\right) }{\sqrt{2\pi } \Gamma (\alpha )}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\beta}{2}  (x-\mu )^2+1\right)^{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}}}.$$

By my math, constant_1= $$\frac{(x-\mu )^2}{2 } + \frac{1}{\beta}$$ and constant_2 = $$-1/2+\alpha$$
It's not clear to me what Gamma distribution multiple is identified. I don't get how the multiple is dealt with once identified.
Can someone write out the steps it skipped? I need to learn.

Make the question self contained. You don't want that people have to open a new tab in a browser, unless it is for details that would clutter the question/post. Coincidentally I opened this question quickly several hours ago while my phone had wifi connection in the bus station, in order to read it and think of an answer for it (I read an answer questions mostly via phone). But I could not do this because the question is incomprehensible without reading the link.

Check the definition of the gamma function, and the value $\Gamma(\alpha+0.5)/\Gamma(\alpha)$.

Are you asking about the integral $\int_0^\infty \tau^\alpha e^{-\beta \tau} d\tau$?

@SextusEmpiricus i'm asking about how the answer gets from the second-to-last step to the last step

That is explained in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/198621/919.

An integral of the form $\int_0^\infty \tau^\alpha e^{-\beta \tau} d\tau$ is related to the gamma function and can be written as  $\int_0^\infty \tau^\alpha e^{-\beta \tau} d\tau = \int_0^\infty (t/\beta )^\alpha e^{-t} d(t/\beta) = \Gamma(\alpha+1)/ \beta^{\alpha+1}$.
