# Expected value of Y = (1/X) where X is Gamma Distribution

Tags: self-study, expected-value, gamma-distribution, moment-generating-function

Let's suppose

$$E\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{M_X(-t)dt}$$

Could you please help me to  find
$$E\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ where
$$X \sim\textrm{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$$ and $$E(X) = \alpha\beta~?$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected value of Y = (1/X) where $X \sim Gamma$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139467/expected-value-of-y-1-x-where-x-sim-gamma)

Comment: @DilipSarwate Not exactly. I had checked it before. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward integration:

Note that since $\mathbb{E}(X) = \alpha\beta$ then the $\beta$ is a scale parameter. Thus

$$
\begin{aligned}
M_X(t) =& (1-\beta t)^{-\alpha}\\
\therefore\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{X}\right) =& \int_0^\infty M_X(-t)dt = \int_0^\infty (1+\beta t)^{-\alpha}dt\\
=&\frac{(1+\beta t)^{-\alpha + 1}}{-\beta(\alpha-1)}\Bigg|_0^\infty = \frac{1}{\beta(\alpha-1)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Also note that the expectation could be computed directly:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{X}\right) &= \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha}\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}dx \\
&=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha - 1)\beta^{\alpha - 1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha} =
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha - 1)\beta^{\alpha - 1}}{(\alpha-1)\Gamma(\alpha - 1)\beta^\alpha}  = \frac{1}{\beta(\alpha-1)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Lastly you can note that since $X\sim\Gamma(\alpha, 1/\beta)$ then $Y=1/X\sim\Gamma^{-1}(\alpha,1/\beta)$ and therefore $$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{X}\right) = \mathbb{E}(Y) = \frac{1}{\beta(\alpha-1)}$$

You can easily look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) for the moments of the inverse gamma distribution